# How to call a library from another one?

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui

I'm trying to create several libraries and to call them. My objective is to call a method of the second one into the first one.

For example, I created two libraries, `library1` and `library2`.

**Library1 code**

```
class LibraryScriptTest1 {
    def log
    def context
    def testRunner
    def library2

    def LibraryScriptTest1(log, context, testRunner) {
        this.log = log
        this.context = context
        this.testRunner = testRunner

        library = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["LibraryTestSuiteTest"]
        module = library.testCases["LibraryTestCaseTest2"].testSteps["LibraryScriptTest2"]
        module.run(testRunner, context)
        this.library2 = context.library2
    }

    int add(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        return firstNumber + secondNumber
    }

    int multiply(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        return firstNumber * secondNumber
    }

    int divide(firstNumber, secondNumber) {
        return this.library2.divide(firstNumber, secondNumber)
    }
}

context.setProperty("library1", new LibraryScriptTest1(log, context, testRunner))
```

**Library2 code:**

```
class LibraryScriptTest2 {
    def log
    def context
    def testRunner

    def LibraryScriptTest2(log, context, testRunner) {
        this.log = log
        this.context = context
        this.testRunner = testRunner
    }

    int substract(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        return firstNumber - secondNumber
    }

    int divide(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        return firstNumber / secondNumber
    }
}

context.setProperty("library2", new LibraryScriptTest2(log, context, testRunner))
```

**Error**

However I'm facing to this error in `library1`:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: library for
>   class: LibraryScriptTest1 Possible solutions: library2 error at line:
>   XX

The corresponding line is the next one:

```
context.setProperty("library1", new LibraryScriptTest1(log, context, testRunner))
```

Anyone can help me to understand and fix that please? Thank you.

Comment: you try to assign value into non-declared variable: `library = testRunner.testCase.testSuite....`

Comment: Even if I use `def library = ...` problem is not solved

Comment: maybe there is another error in the next line?

Comment: This is the only error message.

Comment: look, there are some obvious errors in your code `library = ...` and `module = ...` because those variables are not declared. after fixing those errors, please edit your question and provide fixed code, error message and mark the line where it occurred (with comment)